# UnimplementedError: Graph execution error, in google Collab with keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, text-classification

Hi guys im trying to do some AI text classification with Keras and is giving me this error. Probably my layers are bad or something like that but dont really know the "Unimplemented" error.

This is my code:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    epochs=100,
                    verbose=True,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                    batch_size=10)
```

The error is:
`

```
UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'binary_crossentropy/Cast' defined at (most recent call last)
```

`

Don´t know why is this happening.

Rest of the code:

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

import os
# print(os.listdir("../input"))
plt.style.use('ggplot')


filepath_dict = {'films':   'reviews_filmaffinity.scv'}

df_list = []
for source, filepath in filepath_dict.items():
    df = pd.read_table('reviews_filmaffinity.csv', sep='\|\|', header=0, engine='python')
    df['source'] = source
    df_list.append(df)


df = pd.concat(df_list)


df_films = df[df['source'] == 'films']

df_films['texto'] = df_films['review_title'] + ' ' + df_films['review_text']
sentences = df_films['texto'].values

df_films['polaridad'] = df['review_rate'].apply(lambda  x: 'positivo' if x > 6
                                          else ('negativo' if x < 4
                                                else 'neutro'))
y = df_films['polaridad'].values

sentences_train, sentences_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sentences, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)



vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(sentences_train)

X_train = vectorizer.transform(sentences_train)
X_test  = vectorizer.transform(sentences_test)

X_train

classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
score = classifier.score(X_test, y_test)

print("Accuracy:", score)

input_dim = X_train.shape[1]  # Number of features

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I searched online but i dont figured out how to fix that... its driving me crazy

Comment: paste your complete code. Your loss function too.

Comment: @MohammadAhmed I tried that, It wasnt helpful really, any idea of whats going on?